# Fortran output exponentials to file

Tags: fortran, exponential

I'm having trouble writing exponential numbers to a file. If I set output to be in the form E20.8 and have numbers in the range e-99 to e+99, I'm fine. When I try to output a number less than e-99, such as 1.23456e-100, I get  1.23456000-100 instead (dropping the e, zeros because of E20**.8**). This is problematic for post-processing.

Any suggestions for a fix? Is there another parameter for the Ew.d format for the size of the exponential?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wasn't persistent enough in my searching: the full output format is Ew.d followed by "e" and the number of spaces to leave for the exponential. In my case, E20.8e3 worked great. The answer, for future reference, is here:
http://www.hicest.com/Format.htm

Comment: You should accept your own answer to the question; perhaps it's clearer to include the specific edit descriptor you were looking for while leaving the rest of the link for reference.